# Cakephp modify pot file without i18n

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-1.2

Sometimes I have to change or add one untranslated text to my CakePHP application. In this case I have to run cake i18n to scan all the project's files to produce new pot file, then I use Poedit to update the current catalog with new pot file.

My question is meant by saving time and performance of my computer, Is there any other way to update the catalog with the new untranslated text without having to run cake i18n again?

Comment: How long does it take to rescan your sources? Also: just add it by hand. It's just a text file.

Comment: @decereé Oh thank you, this the first time I noticed that for pot file. I have tried it with po file but it does not succeeded. However, the pot file works so fine.

Comment: @deceze note how nicely he spelled your name - even with autocomplete ;)

Comment: @mark That's a long story, but at the time it was correct... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note though, that to obtain the .mo file eventually, you will require to use a Tool like POedit. The .mo-file is the one that CakePHP uses to fetch the translation that gets output in the e